# Can I use ATX as a cell phone charge station?

Tags: battery-charging, charging, cellphone, atx

Can I use ATX with few "DC-DC LM2596 Step-down Adjustable Power Supply Modules" to make a cell phone charge station?

Comment: Yes, in theory. If you have to ask, maybe you don't have the required skills though, so the answer might be no.

Comment: Why would you if you can buy a safe/efficient/reliable 5 USB port solution for only 18 Euros: http://www.banggood.com/BlitzWolf-40W-Smart-5-Port-High-Speed-Desktop-Charger-With-Power3S-Tech-For-iPhone-iPad-Samsung-p-976084.html  ??

Comment: There is no such thing as a "ATX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean an ATX power supply and charging a 5V phone yes, but you need to modify it first. I will summarize here, but the details are here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Convert-A-Computer-Power-supply-to-a-Bench-Top-Lab/

There is a “power on” wire which needs to be connected to ground for the supply to operate.

In addition without proper load on the supply it will be unstable. This can be solved by making a steady load using a high watt resistor on the 12V rail.

I will point out that these power supplies provide most of their power to 12V and not 5V. The power provided will not be regulated. Phones meant to charge off of USB may not react well to unregulated power.

Also modifying a power supply is not something to be taken lightly, if you do it wrong you can shock yourself.

You can find 5V power supplies up to 60A on a popular auction site for not much more than the price of an ATX power supply. I suggest you get something purpose built.

Comment: The question seems to have significantly changed since I answered it.

Comment: Thank you @HighInBC for detailed answer. My only concern is the ATX power supplies have max 30A on each 12V wires. So if I can divide those as a 1A it will be not harm to ATX I believe. Please correct me, if I'm ask you a dump question.